# RxJava2 PublishSubject subscriber fails to receive items when called from multiple threads using SingleScheduler

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, rx-java2

I have the following unit test in which I try to send 10 `String`s from different threads and test that I receive those `String`s from a single thread. My problem is that this test flaps. Sometimes it succeeds but sometimes I only receive `8` or `9` items and after that the test hangs until the latch times out. Am I using the `SingleScheduler` in the wrong way? Did I miss something else?

```
val consumerCallerThreadNames = mutableSetOf<String>()
val messageCount = AtomicInteger(0)

val latch = CountDownLatch(MESSAGE_COUNT)

@Test
fun someTest() {
    val msg = "foo"

    val subject = PublishSubject.create<String>()
    subject
            .observeOn(SingleScheduler())
            .subscribe({ message ->
                consumerCallerThreadNames.add(Thread.currentThread().name)
                messageCount.incrementAndGet()
                latch.countDown()
            }, Throwable::printStackTrace)

    1.rangeTo(MESSAGE_COUNT).forEach {
        Thread({
            try {
                subject.onNext(msg)
            } catch (t: Throwable) {
                t.printStackTrace()
            }
        }).start()
    }
    latch.await(10, SECONDS)

    assertThat(consumerCallerThreadNames).hasSize(1)
    assertThat(messageCount.get()).isEqualTo(MESSAGE_COUNT)
}

companion object {
    val MESSAGE_COUNT = 10
}
```

If I rewrite this to use a single threaded `ExecutorService` the test no longer flaps so the problem is either with Rx or my lacking knowledge about Rx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RxJava has a requirement that calls to `on*` do not happen at the same time. This means that your code is not thread-safe.

Since only the subject itself is used in a concurrent fashion it should be fixable by serializing (essentially Java's "synchronized") the subject itself using the `Subject<T>.toSerialized()` method.

`val subject = PublishSubject.create<String>()` becomes `val subject = PublishSubject.create<String>().toSerialized()`.

Comment: What do you mean by `same time`? I can't call `onNext` in quick succession? This means that Rx itself is not thread safe. It can happen in real life that two users click on a button at the same time for example and I get two `onNext`s this way.

Comment: It is specified by Rx that anyone who calls the `Observer` interface must make sure there are no concurrent calls. To support cases where this isn't possible there is the `toSerialized()` operators which enforce it with some overhead.